# Laplace transform, Inverse Laplace transform

Tags: transformation, inverse, laplace-transform

Let $(\mathcal{L}f)(s)$ be the Laplace transform of a piecewise continuous function $f(t)$ defined for $t\geq 0$. If $(\mathcal{L}f)(s)\geq 0$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R^+}$ does this imply that $f(t)\geq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  $e^{-st}$ is always a decreasing function of $t$ when $s > 0$, so counterexamples are easy to construct.

**Counterexample:** let $u(t)$ denote the unit step function, i.e.
$$
u(t) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0\\
1 & t \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
Let $f(t) = u(t) - 2u(t-1) + u(t - 2)$.  Confirm that $(\mathcal L f)(s) \geq 0$ for all $s \in \Bbb R^+$, but $f(t) < 0$ for $t \in (1,2)$.